# How do i link domain from one.com to digitalOcean.com?

Tags: web, error-handling, dns, digital-ocean, domain-name

I have a domain name bought at one.com but cant seem to get the dns settup correctly. I followed this turorial from digital ocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean) where I am instructed to use dns from one.com to my site. In this tutorial (http://www.one.com/en/support/guide/manage-your-dns-settings) they explain how to set up the dns, but i dont know witch option to choose. Should i select Web forward, A record, AAAA record, CNAME or TXT records? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A record is the one you should use.
A   RFC 1035    Address record  Returns a 32-bit IPv4 address, most commonly used to map hostnames to an IP address of the host, but it is also used for DNSBLs, storing subnet masks in RFC 1101, etc.

Comment: Hi Scot, thanks for your answer! The only problem with A record is that you need an ip-adress in the destination field. I am instructed to use name server : 
ns1.digitalocean.com.
ns2.digitalocean.com.
I get this error when putting "ns1.digitalocean.com" is the destenation field: The destination must be a valid and supported IP address when A record is selected.

Comment: right, you should have an ip address given to you from your hosting provider but your nameservers are diffrent.

Comment: fyi its NS records to set your nameservers

Comment: Well, every tutorial ive looked at to connect my one.com domain to digital ocean, mentions nameservers. So you are saying i cannot connect nameservers with A record or that i should provide the ip-adress insted of the url ?

Comment: To link a url to another machine you need to configure a nameserver with an a record pointing you domain to an ip address.